# Map error messages to conditions

Tags: java, error-handling

I have a method which checks some preconditions and if everything is fine returns a `success` response object, otherwise `fail` with an appropriate error message.

My problem is that I have a bunch of `if-else`s which are checking some specific condition and if it fails return a `fail` object with a message.

Here is an example code:

```
public Response sendFirstInquiryEmail(long itemId) {

        Item item = itemService.findById(itemId);

        if (item == null) {
            return Response.fail().withComment("Can't find item");
        }

        if (State.NEW != item.getState()) {
            return Response.fail().withComment("Can't send first inquiry to customer for items not in 'NEW' state");
        }

        if (!item.hasNumber()) {
            return Response.fail().withComment("Can't find ticket in OTRS");
        }

        if (!item.isActive()) {
            return Response.fail().withComment("Item is not active anymore");
        }

        if (!item.isReady()) {
            return Response.fail().withComment("Item is not finalized, first inquiry can be send only for processed items");
        }

        send(item);

        return Response.success();

}
```

And here is my response:

```
public class Response {

    private       String  comment;
    private final boolean successful;

    private Response(boolean successful) {
        this.successful = successful;
    }

    public static Response success() {
        return new Response(true);
    }

    public static Response fail() {
        return new Response(false);
    }

    Response withComment(String comment) {
        this.comment = comment;
        return this;
    }

    public String comment() {
        return comment;
    }

    public boolean isSuccessful() {
        return successful;
    }

}
```

Those conditions are getting more and more, and do not like these bunch of `if`. Is there a better way to achieve the same? I was thinking if it is possible somehow to map this conditions with errors, so that I can call some `validate()` which can return the response with a message.

Comment: Is this **real** code or just an example? We only review real code.

Comment: This is the real code, only messages are some random texts. Is it important to put exact messages?

Comment: of course if you have sensitive or private data you can leave the placeholders, but the review will be better with full error messages

Answer (score 3):

I am going to critique your `Response` class. Firstly, I think that code should handle the common cases really well, and, hopefully, success happens often.

I would create a constant `SUCCESS` instance to indicate the success, and all other instances are fails. As a consequence, I would not have the `withComment` method. How about:

```
public final class Response {

    public static final Response SUCCESS = new Response();

    private final String  comment;

    private Response() {
        this.comment = null;
    }

    public Response (String comment) {
        this.comment = Objects.requireNonNull(comment, "Fail responses require a non-null comment");
    }

    public String comment() {
        return comment;
    }

    public boolean isSuccessful() {
        return this == SUCCESS;
    }

}
```

With the above class, any constructed Response is automatically a fail... only the static `SUCCESS` instance is a success.

Your use code then becomes:

```
public Response sendFirstInquiryEmail(long itemId) {

    Item item = itemService.findById(itemId);

    if (item == null) {
        return new Response("Can't find item");
    }

    if (State.NEW != item.getState()) {
        return new Response("Can't send first inquiry to customer for items not in 'NEW' state");
    }

    if (!item.hasNumber()) {
        return new Response("Can't find ticket in OTRS");
    }

    if (!item.isActive()) {
        return new Response("Item is not active anymore");
    }

    if (!item.isReady()) {
        return new Response("Item is not finalized, first inquiry can be send only for processed items");
    }

    send(item);

    return Response.SUCCESS;

}
```

As for all those conditions that are tested in the cascading `if` blocks? Well, there's not much you can do about that. They are guard conditions. Your only option is to perhaps incorporate the cascade somewhere else, but all that does is shift the logic.

I would live with it. It is clear, flows logically, and so on.

Comment: Thanks. You are totally right, success happens in most of the cases, and ```Response``` looks much better in your version.

Answer (score 3):

Years ago I might have suggested you make a ResponseException and throw it instead of returning string-based errors with your Response class.  I think this is the only truly distinct alternative to your list of `if` statements.  But handling exceptions adds complexity, often hurts clarity, and can make isolating code difficult for testing and other purposes.  Exceptions have proven difficult for the caller/client of your code to handle effectively.  [Bill Venners](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=bCTZQi2dpl8) once said, "Throw exceptions at developers, not at code" meaning that if the calling code could recover from an error, don't throw an exception.

A much better solution is to refactor this using an [Or](https://github.com/GlenKPeterson/UncleJim/blob/master/src/main/java/org/organicdesign/fp/Or.java) which is a more general-purpose version of your Response class.  It is also the functional alternative to throwing exceptions:

```
Or<Item,String> getValidItem(long itemId) {

    Item item = itemService.findById(itemId);

    return (item == null)                 ? Or.bad("message 1") :
           (State.NEW != item.getState()) ? Or.bad("message 2") :
           !item.hasNumber()              ? Or.bad("message 3") :
           !item.isActive()               ? Or.bad("message 4") :
           !item.isReady()                ? Or.bad("message 5") :
           Or.good(item);
}

public Or<Item,String> sendEmail(long itemId) {

    Or<Item,String> response = getValidItem(itemId);

    if (response.isGood()) {
        send(response.good());
    }
    return response;
}
```

Now, `getValidItem()` is purely functional.  You could use Haskel-like monads to make `sendEmail()` appear referentially transparent, but it *is* sending an email after all.  State-separation adds its own complexity, so I would leave it.  At least we've broken off a chunk of pure function which should make it easier to test and understand (because we have completely isolated that code from the rest of the system and from the world).

There is probably no good and substantially different way around the big list of `if` statements in Java.  I re-wrote that part using the [ternary operator](http://glenpeterson.blogspot.com/2013/01/ternary-operator-in-java.html) as a more evaluative/functional/brief alternative, but it is not really so different.

I like using the ternary operator for very simple if/else blocks like these, but using `if` works in some situations where `? :` becomes hopelessly confusing. `if` makes it easier to debug any exceptions that are thrown because the line number in the stack trace is more helpful when you break statements into multiple lines.  The ternary operator is effectively a single line.

Answer (score 1):

Returning a `Response` object that encodes either no error or one error is an anti-pattern.  If the action succeeds, return nothing.  If the action fails, throw an exception.

Answer (score 1):

The following is what I consider an extension of [@OldCurmudgeon](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/a/91297/27975)'s ansswer with **three significant deviations/diclaimers**:

1. It's uses Java 8's [`Stream`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/stream/Stream.html) and [`Predicate`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/function/Predicate.html).
2. It turns your `Response` class into an `enum`.
3. Each `Response` `enum` value interacts solely with an `Item` object, i.e. not to be used as a 'generic' `Response` object.

If you are not fine with any of the above, then <s>`Response.fail()...`</s> just take the following as cursory reading... :)

---

So, the `enum` approach isn't too bad an idea, since your original implementation did impose some kind of ordering for the validation steps. Seeing how each validation is chained to an `Item` object, and seeing how a `Response` object constructed with a description is returned from within each `if` statement when the validation fails, got me thinking...

- What if a `Response` can validate itself against an `Item` in an orderly fashion?
- In Java 8 lingo, what if `Response` implements the `Predicate` interface so that it can `test()` an `Item`?
- Also, what if the description is simply the textual representation of my `Response` values?
- What would all these ideas look like?

```
public enum Response implements Predicate<Item> {
    NOT_FOUND(i -> i != null, "Can't find item"),
    NOT_NEW(i -> i.getState() == State.NEW, "Can't send first inquiry to customer for items not in 'NEW' state"),
    NO_TICKET_NUMBER(Item::hasNumber, "Can't find ticket in OTRS"),
    NOT_ACTIVE(Item::isActive, "Item is not active anymore"),
    NOT_READY(Item::isReady, "Item is not finalized, first inquiry can be send only for processed items"),
    SUCCESS(i -> true, "Validation OK");

    private final Predicate<? super Item> successCase;
    private final String failReason;

    private Response(Predicate<? super Item> successCase, String failReason) {
        this.successCase = successCase;
        this.failReason = failReason;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean test(Item t) {
        return successCase.negate().test(t);
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return failReason;
    }
}
```

Returning `failReason` from `toString()` is self-explanatory, so I'll explain why we take in the successful condition aka `Predicate`, but *`negate()`* it when we do our `test()`-ing...

1. Readability, in an unconventional sense. The constructor arguments can be read as "test for **this condition**, *if it fails* use **this reason**". That's why the arguments are named `successCase` and `failReason` (ok, only the `SUCCESS` case doesn't make much sense for `failReason`).
2. So that I can use [method references](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/methodreferences.html) for half the cases.
3. So that I can clearly distinguish the `SUCCESS` case through the negation, by making sure we will not preemptively return it first as described below.

The entire `sendFirstInquiryEmail()` then becomes just:

```
private static Response sendFirstInquiryEmail(long itemId) {
    Item item = itemService.findById(itemId);
    Response result = EnumSet.allOf(Response.class).stream()
            .filter(r -> r.test(item)).findAny().orElse(Response.SUCCESS);
    if (result == Response.SUCCESS) {
        send(item);
    }
    return result;
}
```

In steps:

- Stream on our `Response` values.
- Filter for those where doing our `test()` returns `true` since we are checking for *any validation failures ('failure')* **first**.
- `findAny()`... find any `Response` value corresponding to the failure. This can be `findFirst()` too.
- If there are no failures, `findAny()` will yield an [`Optional.empty()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Optional.html#empty--), so this is when we do an [`orElse()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Optional.html#orElse-T-) to return our `Response.SUCCESS` value.

Can we test this? Of course! Just one more thing... we started with **three significant deviations/disclaimers**, and I need a fourth for the test to work properly:

4. `Item` is an interface

If it's not, then consider the following as more cursory reading too if you have not yet done so. :D

```
public class ResponseTest {

    enum TestItem implements Item {
        NOT_FOUND(null),
        NOT_NEW(State.OLD), // assuming State.OLD exists
        NO_TICKET_NUMBER(false, false, false),
        NOT_ACTIVE(true, false, false),
        NOT_READY(true, true, false),
        SUCCESS(true, true, true);

        private final State state;
        private final boolean hasNumber;
        private final boolean isActive;
        private final boolean isReady;

        private TestItem(State state) {
            this(state, false, false, false);
        }

        private TestItem(boolean hasNumber, boolean isActive, boolean isReady) {
            this(State.NEW, hasNumber, isActive, isReady);
        }

        private TestItem(State state, boolean hasNumber, boolean isActive,
                boolean isReady) {
            this.state = state;
            this.hasNumber = hasNumber;
            this.isActive = isActive;
            this.isReady = isReady;
        }

        @Override
        public State getState() {
            return state;
        }

        @Override
        public boolean hasNumber() {
            return hasNumber;
        }

        @Override
        public boolean isActive() {
            return isActive;
        }

        @Override
        public boolean isReady() {
            return isReady;
        }

        public void verify() {
            assertThat(testSendFirstInquiryEmail(state == null ? null : this),
                    equalTo(Response.valueOf(name())));
            System.out.println("Verified for: " + Response.valueOf(name()));
        }
    }

    @DataProvider(name = "test-cases")
    public Iterator<Object[]> getTestCases() {
        return EnumSet.allOf(TestItem.class).stream().map(v -> new Object[] { v })
                .iterator();
    }

    @Test(dataProvider = "test-cases")
    public void test(TestItem item) {
        item.verify();
    }

    private static Response testSendFirstInquiryEmail(Item item) {
        return EnumSet.allOf(Response.class).stream()
                .filter(r -> r.test(item)).findAny().orElse(Response.SUCCESS);
    }
}
```

The use of the `TestItem` `enum` is to easily generate different `Item` values that will cause the validation to fail at a rule. More importantly, the names on `TestItem` and `Response` matches so that we can do a nifty `name()` trick in our assertion:

```
        // Hamcrest Matchers library
        assertThat(testSendFirstInquiryEmail(state == null ? null : this),
                equalTo(Response.valueOf(name())));
```

What that describes is to call our test method `testSendFirstInquiryEmail()` with the current `TestItem` item (or `null` - the checking of `state == null` is just a convenient way of testing this), and assert that the `Response` value returned has the same name.

`@Test` and `@DataProvider` annotations come from [TestNG](http://testng.org/doc/documentation-main.html#parameters-dataproviders) to handle parameterized testing, and what they do are to iteratively test each `TestItem` by calling its `verify()` method.

Test output snippet:

```
Verified for: Can't find item
Verified for: Can't send first inquiry to customer for items not in 'NEW' state
Verified for: Can't find ticket in OTRS
Verified for: Item is not active anymore
Verified for: Item is not finalized, first inquiry can be send only for processed items
Verified for: Validation OK
PASSED: test(NOT_FOUND)
PASSED: test(NOT_NEW)
PASSED: test(NO_TICKET_NUMBER)
PASSED: test(NOT_ACTIVE)
PASSED: test(NOT_READY)
PASSED: test(SUCCESS)
```

Answer (score 0):

I would recode the list of `if`s into a list of tests and implement them as an `enum`. There are other techniques but `enum`s offer a nice succinct way of doing this.

```
public static class Response {

    private String comment;
    private final boolean successful;
    // Special one meaning success and you can use == on it.
    public static final Response SUCCESS = new Response(true).withComment("All good.");

    private Response(boolean successful) {
        this.successful = successful;
    }

    public static Response fail() {
        return new Response(false);
    }

    Response withComment(String comment) {
        this.comment = comment;
        return this;
    }

    public String comment() {
        return comment;
    }

    public boolean isSuccessful() {
        return successful;
    }

}

enum Test {

    NotNull {

                @Override
                Response test(Item item) {
                    if (item == null) {
                        return Response.fail().withComment("Can't find item");
                    }
                    return Response.SUCCESS;
                }

            },
    NewState {

                @Override
                Response test(Item item) {
                    if (item.getState() != State.NEW) {
                        return Response.fail().withComment("Can't send first inquiry to customer for items not in 'NEW' state");
                    }
                    return Response.SUCCESS;
                }

            },
    HasNumber {

                @Override
                Response test(Item item) {
                    if (!item.hasNumber()) {
                        return Response.fail().withComment("Can't find ticket in OTRS");
                    }
                    return Response.SUCCESS;
                }

            },
    IsActive {

                @Override
                Response test(Item item) {
                    if (!item.isActive()) {
                        return Response.fail().withComment("Item is not active anymore");
                    }
                    return Response.SUCCESS;
                }

            },
    IsReady {

                @Override
                Response test(Item item) {
                    if (!item.isReady()) {
                        return Response.fail().withComment("Item is not finalized, first inquiry can be send only for processed items");
                    }
                    return Response.SUCCESS;
                }

            };

    abstract Response test(Item item);
}

public Response sendFirstInquiryEmail(long itemId) {

    Item item = itemService.findById(itemId);

    for (Test t : Test.values()) {
        Response r = t.test(item);
        if ( r != Response.SUCCESS) {
            return r;
        }
    }
    // All tests succeeded! Send it.
    send(item);

    return Response.SUCCESS;

}
```

Note also I have made a single `SUCCESS` object like @rolfl suggested.

Comment: This code depends on the ordering of enum values in a disjoint way and is thusly from my pov a regression

Comment: @Vogel612 I don't think it's *that* part in this particular use case, since some form of ordering is already imposed in the original implementation.

Comment: @Vogel612 - I feel the extra implied ordering this creates is a feature of the technique. I can now reverse that horrible yoda comparison reversal because I **know** it is not null.